# Cross Site Scripting with uploading XML files

Tags: .net, xss, html-sanitizer-api

I have an application that contains a functionality to upload different types of XML files.

I have implemented cross site scripting detection and prevention in the application using the [HTMLSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) package.

I have faced a problem that the XSS detection is blocking the system from uploading the XML files. It is not possible to list all the XML tags in order to mark them as safe.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Why are you using HTML Sanitizer with XML? Sure, HTML has some things in common but HTML is __not__ XML.

Comment: What I am supposed to use? Is there any other library?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for libraries is OT for [so]. Also, what level of validation/sanitising you need will depend on your application and how the XML is going to be used.